# How to change Tkinter animated figure interval

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, lambda

So I have an **animate()** function that is called at the end of my tkinter application every second which looks like this `ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)`.

The function **animate()** gets called which is listed below as well as the figure and the subplot.

**My question is** how do I make the button (**button1000**) change the **interval** in kline_data? I'm trying to have the initial interval be '1m' or *1 minute* and then click a button and have it animate '5m', '30m' or '1h' intervals.

```
kline_data = client.get_klines(symbol='ETHUSDT', interval='1m', limit=30)
```

Below is the code, though parts are taken out since this is apart of a larger project. **Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)


graph_window = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(7, 5), tight_layout=True)
a = fig.add_subplot(111)

def animate(i):
    kline_data = client.get_klines(symbol='ETHUSDT', interval='1m', limit=30)
    df = pd.DataFrame(kline_data).drop([7, 9, 10, 11], axis=1)
    df.columns = ['Open Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close Time', 'Num of Trades']
    df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']] = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']].astype(
        float)
    df['Open Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Time'], unit='ms')
    df['Close Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close Time'], unit='ms')
    df['EMA7'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=7, adjust=False).mean()
    df['SMA7'] = df['Close'].rolling(7).mean()
    a.clear()
    a.yaxis.tick_right()
    a.margins(x=0.03)
    a.set_title('Last Price of ETHUSDT: ' + str(df['Close'][29]))
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='Close', ax=a)
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='EMA7', ax=a)
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='SMA7', ax=a)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, graph_container)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(controls, borderwidth=5, text='Graph Controls', labelanchor='n', pady=5)
button0000=ttk.Label(labelframe, text="Time:")
button1000=tk.Button(labelframe, text="1m")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
graph_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `animate()` function is being called repeatedly by the `FuncAnimation` object.  Just make the interval a global variable (or other persistent storage such as an instance attribute), and change that variable: the change will be effective as of the next animation frame.

Answer (score 0):

With the insight of @jasonharper is was able to solve this by setting a global variable to '1m'.
I then created a function that would change the interval when a button was pressed.

Here's the working code!

**Edit**: Large portions were left out and in doing so could confuse users in the future. Here is the full, completed code for reference. Be aware this project was completed a while ago so dependencies may be outdated. https://github.com/prestonkelly/Mastermind/blob/master/app.py

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

graph_window = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(7, 5), tight_layout=True)
a = fig.add_subplot(111)


interval = '1m'

def button_changing(id):
    global interval
    if id == 1:
        interval = '30m'


def animate(i):
    kline_data = client.get_klines(symbol='ETHUSDT', interval=interval, limit=30)
    df = pd.DataFrame(kline_data).drop([7, 9, 10, 11], axis=1)
    df.columns = ['Open Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close Time', 'Num of Trades']
    df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']] = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']].astype(
        float)
    df['Open Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Time'], unit='ms')
    df['Close Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close Time'], unit='ms')
    date_values = df['Close Time']
    close_values = df['Close']
    df['EMA7'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=7, adjust=False).mean()
    df['SMA7'] = df['Close'].rolling(7).mean()
    a.clear()
    a.yaxis.tick_right()
    a.margins(x=0.03)
    a.set_title('Last Price of ETHUSDT: ' + str(df['Close'][29]))
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='Close', ax=a)
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='EMA7', ax=a)
    df.plot(x='Close Time', y='SMA7', ax=a)



canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, graph_window)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(graph_window, borderwidth=5, text='Graph Controls', labelanchor='n', pady=5)
button0000=ttk.Label(labelframe, text="Time:")
button1000=tk.Button(labelframe, text="1m", command=lambda: button_changing(1))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
graph_window.mainloop()
```